# Is it possible to add multiple alerts for multiple drop down value choices?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I have a drop down, where when a user picks a choice, it should fire an alert. Here is how I've written it:

```
    function changeddl($this) {
    if ($this.value == "New Posting") {
        alert("Please attach supporting document(s) below.");
    }
}

function changedd2($this) {
    if ($this.value == "SpecialPay") {
        alert("Please attach supporting document(s) below.");
    }
}



function changedd3($this) {
    if ($this.value == "DataEntry") {
        alert("Please attach supporting document(s) below.");
    }
}



function changedd4($this) {
    if ($this.value == "CreditCardACHPosting") {
        alert("Verify CCD or Banking Information has been added.");
    }
}
```

Is there a way to combine all?

Thank you.

Comment: Alerts are usually not a very pleasant user experience. You should think about something more pleasant like a less intrusive popup in the form of a tooltip or similar.

Comment: @Christoph oh thank you for the suggestion. Could you help me in writing this as a tooltip? Would a tooltip work for a drop down choice?

Comment: I agree with @Christoph,  you could also consider  using  a toast. i.e. [jQuery Toast](http://kamranahmed.info/toast)

Comment: You don't need to write this by hand, there are plenty of plugins out there. Simply google for "tooltip plugin".

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code, you could try using a switch and wind up with something like this:

```
function changeddl($this) {
    var alertMsg;
    switch($this.value){
        case "New Posting":
            alertMsg = "Please attach supporting document(s) below.";
            break;

        case "SpecialPay":
            alertMsg = "Please attach supporting document(s) below.");
            break;

        case "DataEntry":
            alertMsg = "Please attach supporting document(s) below.";
            break;

        case "CreditCardACHPosting":
            alertMsg = "Please attach supporting document(s) below.";
            break;
    }

    alert(alertMsg);
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but it won't alert when i do onchange="changeddl(this);

Answer (score 0):

I would just add a data attribute on your options with the message you want.

```
<select id="my_menu">
    <option value="SpecialPay" data-alert-message="This is my message for Special Pay">Special Pay</option>
    <option value="DataEntry" data-alert-message="This is my message for Data Entry">Data Entry</option>
</select>
```

And then the jQuery:

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        $('#my_menu').on('change', function(){
            alert($('#my_menu option:selected').data('alert-message'));
        });
    });
</script>
```

If you rather print an inline message instead of an alert you can always add and element below or above the drop menu such as `<p id="item_added"></p>` and instead of `alert($('#my_menu option:selected').data('alert-message'));` you can do: `$('#item_added').text($('#my_menu option:selected').data('alert-message'));`

Comment: This works well, but when I choose drop down values that aren't the above, I get an "undefined" alert.

Comment: A yes. This is assuming that all your options would have a data-alert-message attribute. If you want to not have messages on all you would just wrap the alert in a condition if($('#my_menu option:selected').data('alert-message')){ ... the behavior code here... }

Answer (score 0):

You could attach an event handler to the select element. For example suppose the id of the element is "choices". Then, you could do the following:

```
$('#choices').change(function() {
    var selectedValue = $('#choices' + ' option:selected').attr('value');
    switch (selectedValue)
    {
        case 'New Posting':
            alert('Please attach supporting document(s) below.');
            break;

        case 'SpecialPay':
            alert('Please attach supporting document(s) below.');
            break;

        case 'DataEntry':
            alert('Please attach supporting document(s) below.');
            break;

        case 'CreditCardACHPosting':
            alert('Verify CCD or Banking Information has been added.');
            break;
    }
});
```

The event handler function does the following: first, it gets the value HTML attribute of the current selected choice from the dropdown list. Then, it uses a switch statement to display the appropriate alert message.

Comment: What would the event handler look like syntax-wise?

Comment: The event handler is the function being passed to the change method.

Comment: would I do select onchange="choices()" ?

Comment: No, it isn't necessary. The code in my answer already attaches the function to the change event.